# Foxpro Meaning Confusion

Tags: foxpro

I couldn't think of a good title for this, so feel free to edit this for me.

I am very very new to Foxpro. We decided to use it because we are trying to upgrade database platforms and wanted something more sophisticated.

Unfortunately, the amount of documentation is very limited.

What is the meaning of `*!*`? Does the second asterisk end the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the start of a comment. If a line starts with *, the whole line is a comment no matter what follows.

However, in the Visual FoxPro IDE, when you right-click and choose Comment, it starts the comment with *!*. That makes it possible to distinguish those comments from other comments.

Oh, and you can set what string it uses for that purpose. Tools | Options, look in the Editor tab.

Tamar

Answer (score 1):

As is usual, Tamar is correct.

Since you are new to Foxpro, you might benefit from spending some time with the free, on-line VFP tutorial videos at:  [Garfield Hudson Tutorial Videos](http://www.garfieldhudson.com/FreeVideos.aspx)

And while it is true that written documentation for FP/VFP has long since become harder and harder to find, you might want to look at the various VFP books at:  [Hentzenwerke Catalog of Books](http://www.hentzenwerke.com/catalog/zcatalogsubject.htm#visualfoxpro)

NOTE:  You don't mention which version of FP/VFP you are using, but if you are not using Visual Foxpro version 9, you should be.

Good Luck